# Representing a logic signature with a digraph

Tags: graph-theory, first-order-logic, monoidal-categories

I'm researching Monoidal Categories and became interested in the concept of signatures. In [Peter Selinger's survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.3347) we can find the definition:

> A simple (categorical) signature Σ consists of a set Σ0 of
> object variables,  a set Σ1 of morphism variables, and a pair of
> functions dom, cod:Σ1→Σ0. Object variables are usually written A, B,
> C, . . ., morphism variables are usually written  f, g, h, . . ., and
> we write f : A → B if dom(f) = A and cod(f) = B.

To program with Monoidal Categories I want a plain-text syntax, such as most programming languages. I came across YAML which has a graph-based spec. I had a pretty simple but powerful idea. I couldn't find any treatment of this topic so I reach out to you for guidance.

Does the following definition support arbitrary multi-sorted signatures based on a digraph, and YAML by extension?

> Given a graph G, a signature Σ consists of Σ0=Σ1=graph nodes,
> dom=predecessors, cod=successors.

Thank you.

---

See also: [The definition of a free monoidal category](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4349363/the-definition-of-a-free-monoidal-category)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't sufficiently arbitrary. For example non-symmetric signatures.

For a complete treatment see *Section 1.6 Fibrations of signatures* in Bart Jacob's *Categorical Logic and Type Theory*.